# Symfony Weekday Select

Tags: forms, symfony4, weekday

this is my first question, so sorry if I miss some information.

In my project I try to create a FormType with a ChoiceType. The ChoiceType should contain the weekdays (eg. monday, tuesday, etc).

Now I was wondering how I should deal with this exactly?
First things which came in my mind are:
- create a new weekday entity and store the weekdays in the database
- put the weekdays in the choices as static array
- somehow define a global array with the weekdays

I do not really like any solution though. So i was wondering if there is a general PHP way to get all weekday names for my ChoiceType. Also I'd like to reuse the same array multiple times (thats why I dont want to use a static array). The database solution could work, but that means I would have to define each weekday in every instance of my project - which also seems not ideal.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Weekdays in database works for your problem. Just make sure that you use the `EnityType` instead of your `ChoiceType`.

Comment: How exactly does that work? Thanks for the help

Comment: I assume you know how to create entities? If yours is called for eg. `Weekday` you can use following in your FormType `$builder->add('weekday', EntityType::class, ['class' => Weekday::class, 'choice_label' => 'name']);` that should work - also make sure that 'name' is your field where you save the weekday names

Comment: I'll try that. Thank you